# during jest how to disable the debug lines from supertest REST calls

Tags: logging, jestjs, strapi

Im using strapi server api testing and every unit produces the log line like below. `verbose` is false in jest config and cannot find where or how to disable this log.

```
[2022-12-18T08:58:43.528Z] debug POST /auth/local (981 ms) 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The fix is not in jest. Jest has no control on those lines as even `strapi` server dumps the exactly same debug lines from their server process.
The fix was to edit `config/middleware.js`

```
logger: {
    level: "warn",
},
```